# Como listar propriedades estáticas (shared property) igual ao do System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, classes, métodos-estáticos

Eu tenho uma estrutura chamada `Servicos` e nela tenho algumas propriedades estáticas.

```
Public Structure Servico

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instalacao As Servico
            Get
                Return New Servico(ServicesType.Instalacao)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property Desativacao As Servico
            Get
                Return New Servico(ServicesType.Desativacao)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property TrocaVeiculo As Servico
            Get
                Return New Servico(ServicesType.TrocaVeiculo)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property TrocaTitularidade As Servico
            Get
                Return New Servico(ServicesType.TrocaTitularidade)
            End Get
        End Property

End Structure
```

Eu gostaria de quando fizer algum tipo de declaração nesse estilo:

```
Dim objServico as Servico
```

Listasse todas as meus serviços igual quando declaramos uma cor.
Uma imagem para melhor entendimento:

[image: Todas as cores são listadas. Porém essas cores não são Enum, e sim Shared Readonly Property]

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Acessar os membros de uma classes ou estrutura (o que dá para obter o mesmo efeito com membros de instância pública) é bem diferente de acessar os membros estáticos (compartilhados) de um tipo. Os membros estáticos só podem ser acessados através do tipo e não da instância, por isso o IDE nem mostra eles. Então não pode acessar:

```
objServico.Instalacao
```

Deve ser:

```
Service.Instalacao
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Object.vb).

[image: Screenshot IDE autocompletion]

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Porém eu tenho certeza que o exemplo que eu dei não é uma Enumeração, isso você pode ver na documentação da Estrutura Color: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/system.drawing.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Na documentação você consegue ver que todas as cores são propriedades estáticas somente leitura.

Comment: É verdade, sem o contexto achei que era a enumeração `Color`. Tirei esta parte mas a resposta não muda.